# Reusing DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, contentpresenter

With a few `GroupBox`es in my UI, I'm modifying their `HeaderTemplate` to add icons in addition to the text caption. Here's my template:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="/Resources/IDCard.png" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This works, however since I have got multiple `GroupBox`es, I was thinking of a way to define this template in `Window`'s `Resources` and then reference it in each `GroupBox`. How can I use `ContentPresenter` (or anything else for that matter) in place of `<Image>` control in the above template and then provide the actual content (icon) in each `GroupBox` separately?

Note: I'm looking for XAML-only solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to use `DynamicResource` lookup (along the lines of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4638822/546730)).

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a bunch.